# How to extract Azure Devops data through ADF into our SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to extract Azure DevOps data from our projects (Epics, Features, PBI and the children of it) through ADF to our SQL server. I'm trying to find step by step guidelines to connect DevOPS and extract the data to our SQL Server. I can't seem to find any instructions to do this.

Is there a link somewhere to be able to do this? Or is there someone who could explain it to me through here? I would gladly appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is an SQL Server issue. Azure DevOps does actually have a REST API service [with documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1). The hardest part of this task would probably be setting up the authentication - you'll need to use the MSAL-DeviceCodeFlow for a headless non-interactive task like this.

Comment: Thanks for the link :). I'm gonna try to set up the authentication.

Comment: Azure DevOps supports [OData queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/odataquery-connect?view=azure-devops)